# Calculating no of heads using CHS formula

Tags: help-files

Use the cylinder, head and sector (CHS) formula to calculate the number of heads of a 2 G bytes disk which has 128 Bytes per sector. Disk has 1024 cylinders and 32 sectors per platter
where 1 G bytes = 1073741824 bytes

I'm new to this. Trying to know what can be the approach.

128*32*heads*1024 =2 * 1073741824
heads = (2 * 1073741824)/128*32*1024

is this right?

Comment: Homework time again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting disk capacity using cylinder-head-sector model](http://superuser.com/questions/841443/counting-disk-capacity-using-cylinder-head-sector-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks right to me.  (Answer is 512 heads.)

Note: 128 bytes per sector is unusual.  512 bytes is far more common, with newer equipment using larger sector sizes (like 4096 bytes).  So this appears to be a school problem.  If there were 512 bytes per sector, that would knock this down to 128 heads.

In old hard drives, 512 actual heads would be ridiculously many.  However, we started making up false (nonsense) numbers when disk capacities grew, to be compatible with BIOS software that permitted such large numbers.  In other words, the hard drives reported "geometry" (CHS) values that did not reflect what was actually in the drive, because that allowed the hard drive to work with more hard drive controllers (which, today, are most commonly built into motherboards, although some commercial systems use dedicated RAID controller hardware).  So, using the formula of C (# of cylinders) times H (number of heads) times S (number of sectors) time sector size (commonly 512 bytes, but your case is specifying something different) = total size, and using the simple algebra-ish techniques you demonstrated, you've reached the right formula.